# Unity 5: Creating a texture from pictures and text

Tags: c#, textures, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to Unity and I'm currently working on school project where we need to fetch images from different social medias. We are building a Virtual Reality application and in the application user can see the images in a room in different contexts like in photoframe etc.

We also have a tablet in the "user's hands" that is displayed when user looks down at it. The screen of this iPad should have a texture that would have "instagram like page" with the actual image, profile image, and related texts like username, locations etc. + small box for Google Maps view where the map is centered on the location where image was taken. I can get all this data already and display the images on the scene, but I really don't know which way I should compose that texture which would be combination of these elements Google Maps (we have that working too), Instagram picture, user and image related data as text and profile picture of user.

I would appreciate some hints which way to go with this. I tried to find someway to put piture a to coordinates x,y on the plane object etc. but couldn't find something like that. Thank you in advance for any suggestions :)

Example Instagram picture: https://instagram.com/p/wb4wRCQeUQ/

Comment: If you are trying to position the texture on the object, learn about UV mapping. Free tools like Blender can help with this, though it is possible to do it in Unity with code or add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to add images to a scene in Unity. You can add the image as a [texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-Textures.html) to a plane or cube or other object by simply dragging it from your assets onto the texture slot in the Material component of the object in question. You can then position your object in the scene. You may have to scale the texture image to fit properly and be aware that if you apply a texture to a cube, you can set it to tile which will repeat the image over the area.

If you wanted to display the image as part of a GUI (so it is "flat" and displays in front of the camera) then you should use the UI Image approach.
[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-image) is a tutorial for displaying a UI image.

If you want to combine separate images into one texture, you could use [Render Texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html). You will need to overlay the images (put one behind the other in the scene) and use a custom camera to take a snap-shot. From the docs:

> Render Textures are special types of Textures that are created and
>   updated at runtime. To use them, you first create a new Render Texture
>   and designate one of your Cameras to render into it. Then you can use
>   the Render Texture in a Material just like a regular Texture. The
>   Water prefabs in Unity Standard Assets are an example of real-world
>   use of Render Textures for making real-time reflections and
>   refractions.

The example from that same page is how to make a quick Render Texture using a camera:

> 1. Create a new Render Texture asset using Assets->Create->Render
>      Texture.
> 2. Create a new Camera using GameObject > Create General >
>      Camera.
> 3. Assign the Render Texture to the Target Texture of the new
>      Camera.
> 4. Create a wide, tall and thin box
> 5. Drag the Render Texture
>      onto it to create a Material that uses the render texture.
> 6. Enter Play Mode, and observe that the box’s texture is updated in
>      real-time based on the new Camera’s output.

Comment: Yeah but I want to display one texture which is constructed from few elements e.g. instagram picture, few lines of text (username, posted at timestamp, count of likes) and google maps centered to the point where the picture was taken. I already get the instagram picture and it's metadata and I can place the google maps as a texture to plane, but I would need to put all these things as one texture on a plane

Comment: You want to combine all the images into one texture? Or is it okay to just overlay them on top of each other?

Comment: More like combining so one image would take roughly 50% horizontally and 25% vertically and other content around it. I guess this is a good start! Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome. Feel feel to upvote my answer or click the green tick if it helps to solve your problem :)